# How do I generate a TSP art?

Tags: command-line

I have 11.10 installed and I am trying to generate TSP art. I am using the instructions given [here](http://wiki.evilmadscience.com/Generating_TSP_art_from_a_stippled_image).

But, I am not sure how to run the commands given in the article. I have tried to run the commands given on the page and get the following:

```
bubba@bubbasbox:~$ /home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/tspart.py/home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/baby04.pbm 
bash: /home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/tspart.py/home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/baby04.pbm: Not a directory
bubba@bubbasbox:~$ /home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/tspart.py
from: can't read /var/mail/tspbitcity
from: can't read /var/mail/tspsolution
/home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/tspart.py: line 74: syntax error near unexpected token `=='
/home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/tspart.py: line 74: `if sys.platform.lower() == 'win32':'
```

So how do I enter the command correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a space beetween `/home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/tspart.py/home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/baby04.pbm`

So, it should be like this

```
/home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/tspart.py  /home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/baby04.pbm
```

Comment: So i ran the command and got bubba@bubbasbox:~$ /home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/tspart.py  /home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/baby04.pbm

from: can't read /var/mail/tspbitcity
from: can't read /var/mail/tspsolution
/home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/tspart.py: line 74: syntax error near unexpected token `=='
/home/bubba/Desktop/tsp_art_tools_0_8_1/tspart.py: line 74: `if sys.platform.lower() == 'win32':'
bubba@bubbasbox:~$ 
bubba@bubbasbox:~$

Comment: @clkbubba this is windows only I guess, So, It wont work on ubuntu.

Comment: how to on unbutu?

Comment: You cant @clkbubba

Comment: According to the linked website, this program *isn't* Windows-only. It looks like there might be a bug in the program, though. At any rate, I can't really understand the error message when it isn't properly line-wrapped. You should edit your question with the error message properly formatted. Then, we might have a chance of finding the problem.